# iterating over two lists with one value

Tags: python, loops

I do not undestand what such loop means((((:

```
for sentence in snippet,phrase:
    result = sentence[:]
```

snippet and phrase are lists containing one string element each. What is in result???

Comment: Well, why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: Also, where did you see this terrible piece of code?

Comment: Zen Show Learning Python The Hard Way. I tried it))) But can not undestand what it do. It seems it goes over two lists one after another

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually iterating over is those two elements (a tuple: `(snippet, phrase)`)- not iterating over the items in each of those. Therefore, `result` stores a shallow copy of `phrase` as that is the last item in the sequence.